# Group an array on an attribute and make that attribut a parent array

Tags: javascript, angular, algorithm, typescript

With An example, I'm basically trying to go from :

```
   [  
   {  
      'a':a1,
      'b':b2
   },
   {  
      'a':a1,
      'b':b5
   },
   {  
      'a':a3,
      'b':b4
   }
]
```

To :

```
 [  
   {  
      'group':'a1',
      'content':[  
         {  
            'a':a1,
            'b':b2
         },
         {  
            'a':a1,
            'b':b5
         }
      ],

   },
   {  
      'group':'a3',
      'content':[  
         {  
            'a':a3,
            'b':b4
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

So in word reformat the array and group elements on an attribute, here `a`

Comment: right, where is the problem?

Comment: Use the `Array.prototype.reduce` function, and come back if you have an issue. We're not here to make your work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient method to groupby on a JavaScript array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)

Comment: If you cant add 3rd party libraries, i suggest you to go with native javascript `reduce`

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way by using lodash GroupBy

https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy

```
_.groupBy([
  {  
    'a':"a1",
    'b':"b2"
  },
  {  
    'a':"a1",
    'b':"b5"
  },
  {  
    'a':"a3",
    'b':"b4"
  }
 ], "a")
```

The first arguments the array you want to group, an the second is the iterator you want to group, the result will be grouped in a array, it will not have the content preoperty.

```
{
   "a1":[
      {
         "a":"a1",
         "b":"b2"
      },
      {
         "a":"a1",
         "b":"b5"
      }
   ],
   "a3":[
      {
        "a":"a3",
        "b":"b4"
      }
   ]
}
```

See if this helps get you going, if not, let me know

Comment: I really need to separate the group name and the content to access is easily in pipe as in my example

Answer (score 0):

If you only want that grouped array then you can achieve using reducer.

```
`let group = data.reduce((r, a) => {
 r[a.a] = [...r[a.a] || [], a];
 return r;
 }, {});`
```

```js
var data =   [  
   {  
      'a':'a1',
      'b':'b2'
   },
   {  
      'a':'a1',
      'b':'b5'
   },
   {  
      'a':'a3',
      'b':'b4'
   }
]
let group = data.reduce((r, a) => {
 r[a.a] = [...r[a.a] || [], a];
 return r;
}, {});
console.log("group", group);
```